# What do I need, to execute a query within a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query that generates the required queries to execute overall.

Can I do this form my original query?

i.e.

```
SELECT distinct 'SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM ' || table_name from all_tab_columns WHERE OWNER='RGSWKF_PRGM' AND COLUMN_NAME like '%TXN_ID%';
```

The above query gives me a list of all the queries I need executing i.e.

```
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM MEETING_TXN_LIST
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM TXN_COMMENT
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM TXN_DEAL_FEE
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM TXN_RISK_ATTRIBUTE_HISTORY
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM XR_TXN_CT_ROLE
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM XR_TXN_CT_ROLE_EXT_HISTORY
```

Above are just some of the results I get from my original query

Is there anyway I could execute the resulting queries from my original query automatically?

So one query that generates all the queries, which I have but I just need the part where it would execute the created queries.

I hope this is not confusing

---

Update:
@thatJeffSMith works fine, however I would of like to reduce clicking through many times to get the desired result.

Looking to now use pl/sql to put all results into an array then get the total amount through there

Comment: you need to find a way to write that result into a file, and then run the generated script. I have no idea how to do that with SQL Developer though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what would you use to do it in another way? maybe sql dev has something similar

Comment: @Moe just something strange : you check for `column_name like '%TXN_ID%'` and  then you make `count(txn_id)` ? You may return tables with a column name `aaa_txn_id2`, and without any `txn_id`. Other point : you wanna count the values of these tables where the `txn_id` value is not null only ?

Comment: @Moe, I'm confused, is this a duplicate of the previous question, or did you bail on that one?

Comment: yes essentially `table_name from all_tab_columns WHERE OWNER='RGSWKF_PRGM' AND COLUMN_NAME like '%TXN_ID%';` gives me all the tables within my db that has 'TXN_ID' as the name. I then want a count of all the 'txn_id' within those specific tables. Not null only would be preferred

Comment: @paqogomez pulled out on that one, I don't think I explained my self clearly.

Comment: thats what I wanted initially. I tried all the answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select a column from all tables in which it resides? (ORACLE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739043/how-to-select-a-column-from-all-tables-in-which-it-resides-oracle)

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Developer, you can ask to take the query results and execute them as a new script.

[image: So run as script, then hit the button on the results toolbar]

Then run that

[image: Use the execute as script button to run all of them]

Answer (score 1):

You can provide something like that:

```
create or replace function get_count_for_table(iv_table in varchar2, iv_column in varchar2 default '1') return number is
  ln_result number;
  TYPE rcur IS REF CURSOR;
  l_cur rcur;
begin
  open l_cur for 'select count('||iv_column||')  from ' || iv_table;
  fetch l_cur into ln_result;
  close l_cur;
  return ln_result;
end get_count_for_table;
```

and after that:

```
select table_name, column_name, get_count_for_table(table_name, column_name) 
  from ( SELECT distinct table_name, COLUMN_NAME 
           from all_tab_columns 
          WHERE OWNER='RGSWKF_PRGM' 
            AND COLUMN_NAME like '%TXN_ID%');
```

**Note that**:

Column parameter is optional.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to get just a general idea of how much data is in each table you may want to consider:

> SELECT table_name, num_rows FROM all_tables where owner = 'YOUR_SCHEMA_OWNER';

Answer (score 0):

Just a little bit more on Brian's answer, with the "existing column name" constraint.

```
select  table_name, num_rows
from dba_tables dt
where exists (select null
              from all_tab_cols atc
              where atc.table_name = dt.table_name
              and atc.owner = dt.owner
              and atc.COLUMN_NAME like '%TXN_ID%')
and owner = 'RGSWKF_PRGM';
```

**CAUTION**

This won't give you the desired result if %TXN_ID% is nullable and you want only the non null results...

**CAUTION 2**

you may need to execute a command to have up-to-date datas in dba_tables

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(ownname => 'RGSWKF_PRGM');
```

Comment: I get this after running this query: 
`ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"`

Comment: @Moe, but look at the "CAUTION"

Comment: But would this be a reason why I'm getting the missing expression error though?

Comment: @Moe the missing expression was coming from a typo in my answer, I edited again, sorry.

Comment: thanks Raphael, it is executing. But I am not too sure it is giving me what I want exactly. Ant tbh I dont completeley understand what is going on in your query, could you breifly explain what your doing there?

Comment: @Moe : it's a query on a statistic view (dba_tables), which contains an approximation (if you don't gather stats just before querying it) of the rows of the tables. We test, on the all_tab_cols view, if the tables contains a column with a `TXN_ID` name. => FINALLY : the query does : `count all the rows of the tables which have a column with a name like TXN_ID`. That's maybe not what you really want.