# How to set dynamic parameter in Method_4?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm using Oracle Method_4 to use dynamic query and I want to set Dynamic Parameters .

Parameters sets by many users in run-time.

like this:

```
select * from table(method4.dynamic_query(
q'[
    select replace(
        q'!
            select '#TABLE_NAME#' table_name, count(*) a from #TABLE_NAME# 
                where id = &Parameteres
        !', '#TABLE_NAME#', table_name) sql_statement
    from user_tables
    where table_name like 'TEST%'
]'
));
```

my question is:

if user set param_1 then :

```
select * from tb_1 
where col_1 = &param_1
```

if user set param_2 then:

```
select * from tb_1 
where nvl(&param_2,col_2) = col_2
```

if user set param_1,param_2 then:

```
select * from tb_1 
where col_1 = &param_1 
and nvl(&param_2,col_2) = col_2
```

like execute a query with dynamic where clause.

How can I do this ?

Comment: @jonheller1 I thinl you are the only one who can help me

Comment: Hello, an welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] and post a [mcve].  Thank you

Comment: @OldProgrammer I edit my question

Comment: @MohammadTaleshi It looks like you're using Method4 for the dynamic-SQL-in-SQL capabilities, not necessarily for the return-dynamically-defined-columns feature.  If the columns are going to be static, you might be better off using `DBMS_XMLGEN`, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24764886/409172).  It allows you to build dynamic SQL, and has less restrictions on how it's used.
By the way, Stack Overflow notifications don't work if I'm not already involved with the question, it was just luck that I found this.  You can always email me if you want me to look at a question.

Comment: @JonHeller Thank you. but I want to use dynamic parameter in my query ( the query is static but where clauses are dynamic) I edit my question. and one more thing, I cant find your email. Would you write it here please

Comment: @MohammadTaleshi I'm not an expert in Apex, but I'm guessing the issue might be that newer versions of Apex don't allow you to specify "PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL query" when you create the page.  However, once you create a page based on a static query, you can go back and change the region's Source type.  Try doing that with a simple PL/SQL function like `begin
   return 'select 1 a from dual';
end;`.  Let me know how that works.

Comment: @JonHeller I sent you an email. please check your email (my mail: taleshi.mt@gmail.com ---- your mail : jon@jonheller.org). by the way, I want use this version and I want to run dynamic SQL statements without custom PL/SQL

Comment: @MohammadTaleshi Sorry for my late reply.  I saw your email but I'm still not sure I understand the question.  I'm not familiar with Oracle APEX and exactly what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @JonHeller I want to use method4 for dynamic query. that's it. can I?

Comment: @MohammadTaleshi Yep, you can certainly do that.  But it depends on the context.  For example, your Method4 query will run fine in SQL\*Plus if you created a table like this: `create table test1 as select 1 id from dual;`.  SQL\*Plus will prompt you for the parameter and you can enter `1`, and it will return that data.  But I'm not sure how the parameters work in APEX.

Comment: @JonHeller I think its not work for me. by the way, thank you so much for your help